# PhalconPHP - redirection to home page always adds /index in the URI

Tags: redirect, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I'm working on my first app in PhalconPHP so I'm deep in the documentation while working, but this doesn't seem to be covered.

Let's say that my app is running on www.myapp.tld. In some situations I need to redirect the user back to the home page and for that I'm using the following code:

```
if ($haveToRedirect) {
    $this->response->redirect();
    $this->view->disable();
    return;
}
```

Instead if redirecting to www.myapp.tld, the user is redirected to www.myapp.tld/index. I've tried different redirect calls, but all give the same result:

```
    $this->response->redirect('');
    $this->response->redirect('/');
    $this->response->redirect('/', TRUE);
```

In the app's bootstrap I've set the BaseUri to be '/':

```
$di->set('url', function() {
    $url = new Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
    $url->setBaseUri('/');
    return $url;
});
```

Is there a way to avoid "index" being added and just have it redirect to "www.myapp.tld"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of redirection to "/index" was actually in the Permission class I made several weeks ago. It had:

`$this->response->redirect('index');`

for every controller that guest could not access to. Since I added new controllers I was continuously redirected to index, and noticed that redirect comes from somewhere else when I removed the conditional redirects I've put in the controller.

Anyway, this is it. Lesson learned - next time grep for 'index' before asking for help. :)

Answer (score 1):

If a file is not specified, you will be directed to the index page in that directory by default.  You need to specify a file location.  Also try URI, not URL

Comment: I understand that I am redirecting to index page, as I've not specified anything. The index page is on both of these URLs:

`www.myapp.tld/index`
`www.myapp.tld/`

I'd just prefer to use only the latter one.

Comment: You can control wheather or not the trailing index is shown.  You need to create a .htaccess file.  Here is some helpful documentation on this subject.[Remove index](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html).

Comment: This is actually removing the index.php file from the URL. I'm using Nginx and my configuration already rewrites the URI to the index.php parameter per PhalconPHP specification.

`location @rewrite {
 rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
}`

The problem I have right now is that index controller's name gets called in the url, while it is not needed.

Comment: This should be an easy fix.  Phalcon is boasting on their beautiful URL's [click here](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial.html#beautiful-urls)